# rpcbind.service won't start

Tags: centos, nis

I am trying to configure an NIS server on my CentOS 7 VM. It is a fresh VM (VMware Workstation 12) and all I did was run the following commands

```
yum install ypbind ypserv rpcbind
/usr/lib64/yp/ypinit -m
echo "ypserver 127.0.0.1" >> /etc/yp.conf
```

I added localhost as the NIS server. When I tried to start the services under Systemd I get the following errors

```
systemctl start ypserv.service
journalctl -xe


-- Unit rpcbind.service has begun starting up.
Jan 06 19:13:07 localhost.localdomain rpcbind[4306]: /sbin/rpcbind: symbol lookup error: /sbin/rpcbind: undefined symbol: libtirpc_set_debug
Jan 06 19:13:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rpcbind.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jan 06 19:13:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RPC bind service.
-- Subject: Unit rpcbind.service has failed
```

Which is then causing `ypserv.service` not to start due to depencies. Does anyone know what this means. Should I even be wasting my time with NIS?

Edit:
Also failed to mention. When I ran `ypinit -m` I got all of these messages.

```
We need a few minutes to build the databases...
Building /var/yp/home/ypservers...
Running /var/yp/Makefile...
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/var/yp/home'
Updating passwd.byname...
failed to send 'clear' to local ypserv: RPC: Port mapper failureUpdating passwd.byuid...
failed to send 'clear' to local ypserv: RPC: Port mapper failureUpdating group.byname...
failed to send 'clear' to local ypserv: RPC: Port mapper failureUpdating group.bygid...
```

Edit 2: 
So I am guessing there is something wrong with the `/var/yp/Makefile` that is supposed to run on the databases. I am looking at it now but I don't see anything unusual so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web search for the error suggests that it's a known [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1396291). Once it's fixed (or `libtirpc` is installed manually), `rpcbind` should start.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't look very hard  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1396291

Comment: That's the same bug# I referenced in my answer :-)

Comment: Right, I didn't even realize that. derp